# Trying to upload media to the Meta Whatsapp API but running into errors

Tags: dart, facebook-graph-api, whatsapp

**Context**: I need to send media templates in which I need to send local files. Thus I need to  upload the files to the WhatsApp API to get the Media Id, which I can then use to send the message templates.
**The issue**: I am running into errors while sending the post request to the server through DART. However the same call is working when sent through postman. I have tried sending the data both as a JSON and as form-data, but both are returning errors. I am attaching the code below, as well as the errors I am facing. Any help is really appreciated.
Getting the file path

```
upload() async{
    if(await Permission.storage.isGranted){
      FilePickerResult? choice = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(allowMultiple: false);
      String? path = choice?.files.single.path;
      if(path != null){
        uploadJson(path);
        // uploadFormData(path);
      }
    }else{
      Permission.storage.request();
    }
  }
```

Uploading JSON

```
uploadJson(String path) async{
    File imgfile = File(path);
    Uint8List imgbytes = await imgfile.readAsBytes();
    String bs4str = base64.encode(imgbytes);
    print(bs4str);
    var headers = {
      'Authorization': variables.authorizationToken,
      "Content-Type": 'application/json',
    };
    var body = jsonEncode({
      'file': '$bs4str;type=image/jpeg',
      'messaging_product':'whatsapp'
    });
    Response response = await post(Uri.parse('${variables.baseURL}${variables.phoneNumberId}/media'), headers: headers, body: body);
    print(response.body);
  }
```

Uploading as Form-data

```
uploadFormData(String path) async {
    var headers = {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer EAAGtvNhUHUIBANf5KvyxnZCUKcRn3jTJgPZBR2AbbVhZBZBO7GjoDCnS26FQT6Nr6qdRV993ZCJEbGwiqZCdQ7TZBJX8S6KXQdOTgmSf9ue7GCEN1IL3yqfAUEIN1bw0nyvptHeZBFCsdfwpxZAcS1ZCbCdmqArZC81orVbYRkzJy1h7ChOAygmrchfFtJAapykZAadruFqOWwcVvtudMezse94zENBNVZA0k7pAZD',
    };
    var request = MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse('https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/106822672107550/media'));
    request.fields.addAll({
      'messaging_product': 'whatsapp'
    });
    request.files.add(await MultipartFile.fromPath('file', path));
    request.headers.addAll(headers);

    Response response = await Response.fromStream(await request.send());
    print(response.body);
  }
```

Error for JSON:

```
    flutter: {"error":{"message":"An unknown error has occurred.","type":"OAuthException","code":1,"fbtrace_id":"AE72st2KT8wJFQ_wYvrcJY6"}}
```

Error for Form-Data:

```
flutter: {"error":{"message":"(#100) Param file must be a file with one of the following types: audio\/aac, audio\/mp4, audio\/mpeg, audio\/amr, audio\/ogg, audio\/opus, application\/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application\/msword, application\/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document, application\/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation, application\/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application\/pdf, text\/plain, application\/vnd.ms-excel, image\/jpeg, image\/png, image\/webp, video\/mp4, video\/3gpp. Received file of type 'application\/octet-stream'.","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"AfsxKl38CW7hUF_ixMzNha9"}}
```

Comment: Your JSON attempt make little sense to begin with (sending a file path is something different than actually upload a file), and with your other one, it looks like your system is not able to automatically detected the correct Content-Type to use, so it sends `application/octet-stream` instead. So you might have to provide the proper content type for this upload yourself then.

Comment: follow the postman collection of [meta business api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/on-premises/get-started/postman/?translation)

Comment: @CBroe I am new to this so I am making some dumb mistakes, but now I tried to send the JSON by encoding the file into a base64 string (still don't know if that's right, sorry if it's not) still running into the same error. I also added the Content-Type as 'multipart/form-data' but still running into an error, I guess i have to add a boundary, but I don't understand how to do that. Would appreciate your help.

Comment: Boundaries for a multipart request are not something you should have to create yourself (unless you are working very low-level), usually the library you are using to make the request, should handle that for you. And if the API already recognized a parameter named `file` in what you are sending, then the issue is probably not with the boundary to begin with. The error message says you are sending the wrong content type. The `MultipartFile` class allows you to explicitly _specify_ the content type, so try that. https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/MultipartFile-class.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the Mime-type of the file. The Multi-Part file class needed the mime-type of the file to be declared while uploading the file, or the file was automatically being uploaded as an octlet-stream. The code to the working request is posted below.

```
        var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse('https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/${variables.phoneNumberId}/media'));
    request.headers.addAll({
      'Authorization': variables.authorizationToken,
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    });
    request.fields.addAll({
      'messaging_product': 'whatsapp',
      'type': 'application/pdf'     
    });

    // The MIME type of the image or file
    const mimeType = 'application/pdf';
    // Open the image file
    var file = File(path);

    // Create a MultipartFile from the File object
    final multipartFile = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
      'file',
      file.path,
      contentType: MediaType.parse(mimeType),
    );

    // Create a request body containing the multipart file
    request.files.add(multipartFile);

    // Send the request
    final response = await request.send();

    // Check the response status code
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      String body = await response.stream.bytesToString();
      var json = jsonDecode(body);
      print(json['id']);
    } else {
      print(response.reasonPhrase);
    }
```